# How to iteratively integrate a function and sum the result of each iteration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to repeatedly integrated a function and add the result of each iteration. Suppose I start a with a function $f(x) = x$ , I want to integrated it, it will be $x^2/2$, and again integrating, it will be $x^3/6$, and at the end I want to get the result $x^2/2+x^3/6$.

Please help me how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to `mathematica.SE`. This site is for _Mathematica_ programming related questions. If you have some code, please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way using `Reap` and `Sow` with `Nest` instead of `NestList`, just to spice things up. Performance is identical on my machine.

```
f[fun_, n_Integer?Positive] := Total @@ Reap[Nest[Sow[Integrate[#, x]] &, fun, n]][[2]]
```

Which you can use for any nonnegative `n`, where `fun` is the function you which to iteratively integrate, like this:

f[x, 2]

> `x^2/2 + x^3/6`

f[Log[x], 5]

> ```
>  -x - (3 x^2)/4 - (11 x^3)/36 - (25 x^4)/288 - (137 x^5)/7200 +   x Log[x] + 1/2
>      x^2 Log[x] + 1/6 x^3 Log[x] + 1/24 x^4 Log[x] +   1/120 x^5 Log[x]
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
NestList[Integrate[#, x] &, x, 2] // Rest // Accumulate
```

to get the list of successive iterations or

```
NestList[Integrate[#, x] &, x, 2] // Rest // Total
```

to obtain only the last element.

Comment: Remarkable that for a big number of iterations it is almost as fast as exact `Sum[x^n/n!, {n, 2, m}]`!

Answer (score 0):

```
Total@Rest@NestList[Integrate[#, x] &, x, 2]
```